# AngularJS. Передача значений переменных из Url

Tags: json, angularjs, url

Добрый день. 
Прошу подскажите, как извлекать переменные из URL строки и подставлять в код Angular (парсинг json):

```
  var sortApp = angular.module('sortApp', [])
  var vm = this;
    vm.name = '2017-11-01';
  sortApp.controller('mainController', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.sortType     = 'stat_date'; 
    $scope.sortReverse  = false;  
    $scope.searchFish   = '';     
    $http.get('http://www.mydomen.ru/all?from=01.01.2017&to=01.12.2017').success(function(data) {
            $scope.Users = data;
            });

  });
```

Данный скрипт будет исполняться в результате перехода на страницe, типа http://www.getmyjson.ru/getreportjson.html Я бы хотел передавать по этому урл две переменные - *Дата начала периода* и *Дата окончания периода*. Например, так:
http://www.getmyjson.ru/getreportjson.html?data1=01.01.2017&data2=01.12.2017 А затем эти переменные подставлять сюда:

```
$http.get('http://www.mydomen.ru/all?from=data1&to=data2').success(function(data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для поиска в Url используйте сервис $location, подробнее можно почитать в [официальной документации](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#search), в данном случае будет браться текущий URL.

```
 var sortApp = angular.module('sortApp', [])
 var vm = this;
 vm.name = '2017-11-01';
sortApp.controller('mainController', function($scope, $http, $location) { //необходимо добавить его в зависимости
$scope.sortType     = 'stat_date'; 
$scope.sortReverse  = false;  
$scope.searchFish   = '';     
$http.get('http://www.mydomen.ru/all',
     {params:{
      from: $location.search('data1'),
      to: $location.search('data2')}
     }).success(function(data) {
        $scope.Users = data;
        });
  });
```